# My JSON parsing doesn't work

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON provided by an API. The code is the following:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
    let values = responseJSON!["feeds"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
    print("JSON")
    print(responseJSON)
    print("Feeds")
    print (values)
    for value in values {
        if let temp=value["field1"] as? Float {
            self.temperatures.append(temp)
            print(temp)
        }
    }
}
```

But the result for values is like:

```
[["field1": 12.5004340278, "entry_id": 1, "created_at": 2018-03-10T16:02:41Z], 
["field1": 12.5004340278, "entry_id": 2, "created_at": 2018-03-10T16:03:41Z], 
["field1": 12.5004340278, "entry_id": 3, "created_at": 2018-03-10T16:03:56Z], 
["field1": 11.6866319444, "entry_id": 4, "created_at": 2018-03-10T16:06:07Z], 
["field1": 12.2291666667, "entry_id": 5, "created_at": 2018-03-10T16:06:23Z]]
```

After that, it doesn't print my temp. Any idea why? Thanks!

---

FYI, this is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    "feeds": [{
        "created_at": "2018-03-10T16:02:41Z",
        "entry_id": 1,
        "field1": "12.5004340278"
    }, {
        "created_at": "2018-03-10T16:03:41Z",
        "entry_id": 2,
        "field1": "12.5004340278"
    }, {
        "created_at": "2018-03-10T16:03:56Z",
        "entry_id": 3,
        "field1": "12.5004340278"
    }, {
        "created_at": "2018-03-10T16:06:07Z",
        "entry_id": 4,
        "field1": "11.6866319444"
    }, {
        "created_at": "2018-03-10T16:06:23Z",
        "entry_id": 5,
        "field1": "12.2291666667"
    }]
}
```

Comment: field1 looks like `Double` not `Float`

Comment: In you are using Swift 4, read up on `Decodable`. And please include the full JSON

Comment: even with Double is the same issue

Comment: It's undoubtedly because the server returned it as a string. When you print it, the quotes can be omitted. Note the lack of quotes around the datetime strings, too.

Comment: `{
"feeds":[
   {
     "created_at":"2018-03-10T16:02:41Z",
     "entry_id":1,
     "field1":"12.5004340278"
   },
{
"created_at":"2018-03-10T16:03:41Z",
"entry_id":2,
"field1":"12.5004340278"
},
{
"created_at":"2018-03-10T16:03:56Z",
"entry_id":3,
"field1":"12.5004340278"
},
{
"created_at":"2018-03-10T16:06:07Z",
"entry_id":4,
"field1":"11.6866319444"
},
{
"created_at":"2018-03-10T16:06:23Z",
"entry_id":5,
"field1":"12.2291666667"
}
]
}`

Comment: @Rob I also saw these, but I'm really new in swift and I don't know how it should appear and why is that

Comment: But I agree with the others that you really should consider using `JSONDecoder`. See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temperature is a string in your JSON, so you have to convert the string to a `Double`:

```
if let temp=value["field1"] as? String, let temperature = Double(temp) {
    ...
}
```